# Featured Item Slider with orchard 1.7 is not working

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

how to use Featured Item Slider module with orchard 1.7 there is no image upload option on it.

can some one help me or give link of other slide module for orchard cms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade it in order to use Media Library instead of Media (used by Orchard 1.6 and earlier)

Comment: thanks for reply ...i am new in orchard ...can you help to do it

Comment: Featured Item Slider module is a third party module. Never used it. But, you can build your own  slide widget using projection widget and custom shape. Check this as well: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/431145